# AJAX Modal Popup Extender not shown - Sys is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

I have an ASP.Net WebForms project (using C# in VS 2013)  in which  I call an instance of AJAX Popup Extender. Ihave added AjaxControlToolKit and AjaxControlTookitStaticResources using NuGet. Recently, the popup form has stopped being shown. When I try to show the popup by clicking the target control, it does not appear using FireFox as the target browser. The Firefox console shows a number of errors as shown below. The first error is

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(6,25981-25982): run-time error JS1014: Invalid character: \
(6,25981-25982): run-time error JS1003: Expected ':': \
(6,44631-44635): run-time error JS1197: Too many errors. The file might not be a JavaScript file: 'ss'
(6,25816-25829): run-time error JS1301: End of file encountered before function is properly closed: function(e,b)
(6,44635-44636): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';
': Z
(6,45814-45815): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: ^
(6,45815-45816): run-time error JS1197: Too many errors. The file might not be a JavaScript file: |
 */
```

What can I do to make the popup show again?[image: Errors when running web application in FireFox]

Code relating to the popup is

```
    CancelControlID="cmdCloseButton" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">  </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

    <asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" Text="Test Popup" Width="177px"/> 

   <%--<asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" Text="Test Popup" Width="177px" Style="display:none" />--%> 

   <asp:Panel ID="Panl2" runat="server" Width="280px" Height="180px"  CssClass="modalPopup" align="left" style="display:none">  
        <br />&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Need to caption multiple photos? <br /><br />
           &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Click <a href="Why Use the Windows Downloadable Application.htm" target="_blank">here</a> for details of desktop app. <br /><br />
           &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp To hide this message and watermark on <br />
          &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp captioned photo, <a href="BuyLicense.aspx" target="_blank">buy License</a>. 

         <asp:Button ID="cmdCloseButton" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass ="closebutton" 
             OnClick ="cmdCloseButton_Click" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>  
   </asp:Panel>
```

The Site.Master code is

```
%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="CaptionProWebMob.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> Caption Pro Web</title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">     
          <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>  
    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" /> 
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="HeadContent" />


</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">   

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="False">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272931&clcid=0x409 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>

            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <%--<asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />--%>
            <%--Site Scripts--%>

        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <header>
    </header>
    <div id="body"  ondragstart="dragStartHandler1(event);">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" >
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContent" >
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Caption Pro Web</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I add EnableCDN="true" to the line defining ScriptManager1 in Site.Master.aspx as shown below

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="False" EnableCdn="true" >
```

then the popup screen appears OK.

However, drag and drop of files onto the main form using AJAX AsyncFileUpLoad now does not work if the VS project is run as Administrator (at least for Firefox): it works OK if the VS project is not run as Administrator.